# Write to files with long names in VBA for Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, applescript

I have a subroutine which writes a text to a `.txt` file in VBA:

```
Sub WriteToFile(fileName as String, content as String)
  Open fileName For Output As #1
  Print #1, content
  Close #1
End Sub
```

This subroutine works well under Windows. However, I realize that under Mac, for any `targeFile` which has more than 29 characters, an error `Bad file name or number` will be raised on the line `Open fileName For Output As #1`.

But I do need to write to a lot of files whose name is long...

Actually, this issue is quite common. For instance, [this link](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac008.htm) also mentions that `There are problems with long file names when you use Dir on a Mac, 27/28 characters (without the ext) is the maximum(with the extension this is 32 characters).`

It seems that `AppleScript` may be a solution for this. But as I am looking for a workaround for **writing** instead of `Dir`, I have not found a precise solution for **writing**.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

<sup>This is a more robust version of an earlier, since-deleted answer. Unlike the deleted answer, which used `do shell script`, this answer uses only AppleScript features in the AppleScript command string, and also correctly escapes the arguments that get embedded in the command string.</sup>

Try the following VBA procedure, which synthesizes an AppleScript command string for writing to a file and executes it with `MacScript`.

```vbs
' - Specify the output filename either as a mere filename -
'    in which case the file is created in the active workbook's folder -
'    or as a HFS path (with ':' as the path separator).
' - Note that line breaks in `content` are written as defined,
'    and that on a Mac `vbNewLine` is chr(13) (CR == \r) only.
'    If you want Unix-style LF (\n) line breaks instead, use chr(10) explicitly.
' Example:
'      WriteToFile "test.txt", "Hello, world." & Chr(10)
Sub WriteToFile(fileName As String, content As String)
    Dim filePath, filePathEscaped, contentEscaped, asCmd
    ' If the filename contains no path component, default to the active workbook's path.
    If InStr(fileName, ":") = 0 Then
        filePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & ":" & fileName
    Else
        filePath = fileName
    End If
    ' In case the file path or input string contain double quotes, we must
    ' \-escape them for inclusing in the AppleScript command string first.
    filePathEscaped = Replace(filePath, """", "\""")
    contentEscaped = Replace(content, """", "\""")
    ' Synthesize the AppleScript command string.
    asCmd = _
       "set fRef to open for access """ & filePathEscaped & _
                                    """ with write permission" & Chr(13) & _
       "set eof fRef to 0" & Chr(13) & _
       "write """ & contentEscaped & """ to fRef" & Chr(13) & _
       "close access fRef"
    ' Execute the AppleScript command string.
    ' Any error will generically be reported as "Invalid procedure call or 
    ' argument", unfortunately.
    MacScript asCmd
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

An inelegant and unsatisfying (but easy) alternative is to

1. Write the output to a reserved filename that's short enough not to cause the problem
2. After the writing is complete and the file is closed, use FileCopy to copy that short-named file to the long name you actually want
3. Delete the short-named file

It turns out that FileCopy isn't so finicky about filename length.

You'd probably want to encase it all in checks to make sure that the reserved name doesn't exist before you write, and to make sure that you delete the file with the reserved name if any kind of hitch develops while you have it open. Or you can be open with the user about what you're doing and query the user for both names at the outset.  -HTH

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread but...

As a workaround, create the file with a short name and then use the VBA statement `Name` to rename the file to the longer name.  This works in Excel Mac 2011.

```
  Open "Macintosh HD:Users:joe:Documents:SO-23587418.txt" For Output As #1
  Print #1, "Hello world!"
  Close #1

  Name "Macintosh HD:Users:joe:Documents:SO-23587418.txt" As "Macintosh HD:Users:joe:Documents:SO-23587418-11111111112222222222333333333344444444445555555555.txt"
```